# Combinatorially counting the Riemann tensor's degrees of freedom

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, combinatorial-proofs

One famous way to count the DOFs of $R_{abcd}$ on an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold is as follows:

- $ab$ has $\binom{n}{2}$ DOFs because $R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd}$;
- Since $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$, the Riemann tensor's DOFs number at most$$\binom{\binom{n}{2}+1}{2};$$
- We have one last constraint viz. $R_{a\left[bcd\right]}=0$, so the final answer is$$\binom{\binom{n}{2}+1}{2}-\binom{n}{4}\stackrel{\star}{=}\frac{1}{3!}\binom{n^{2}}{2},$$where $\stackrel{\star}{=}$ follows by chugging through algebra (both sides are $\tfrac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}$).

My question is whether we can prove the RHS immediately with a different combinatorial argument. (If so, the above equation could be proved by double-counting the tensor's DOFs.)

My first thought was to pair $n^2$ values of $ac$ with $n^2-1$ values of $bd$, then lose a factor of $3!$ through other symmetries. But this won't work, because each choice of $ac$ doesn't disqualify just one value of $bd$; if $R_{abcd}\ne0$, $a\ne b$ and $c\ne d$, and at most $(n-1)^2$ values of $bd$ work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but here is another way to find the dimension of the space of curvature tensors. On bottom of page 881 of the paper by Berger, Bryant, Griffths titled "The Gauss Equations and Rigidity of Isometric Embeddings", they state that the space of curvature tensors is the kernel of the surjective linear map
\begin{align*}
\Lambda^2V^*\otimes\Lambda^2V^* &\rightarrow V^*\otimes\Lambda^3V^*\\
R_{abcd} &\mapsto R_{abcd}-R_{bacd}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the dimension of this space is
$$
\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)^2 - n\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}.
$$
A straightforward calculation shows that this is equal to
$$
\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}.
$$
The proof in the paper that the linear map above is surjective and the kernel is the space of curvature tensors follows from the decomposition of tensor products of $V^*$ into irreducible representations of $GL(n)$ and that the space of curvature tensors is an irreducible subspace. However, I think it might be possible to prove this using your "bare hands".

Comment: "I'm not sure what exactly you want" - You've presented a proof the result is $\binom{n}{2}^2-n\binom{n}{3}$, which is a different combinatorial perspective again. In particular, you've facilitated a proof by double-counting that$$\binom{\binom{n}{2}+1}{2}-\binom{n}{4}=\binom{n}{2}^2-n\binom{n}{3}.$$Note both expressions subtract a term via some constraint to avoid DOF overcounting (in the leftmost expression, $R_{a[bcd]}=0$ had this effect). But as I said, what I want is a direct explanation - without such arithmetic - for why there should be $\binom{n^2}{2}$, divided by $3!$, DOFs.

Comment: If you look at the paper, you can see that the image of the map is the direct sum of two $GL(n)$-irreducible subspaces, $V^*{}^{(2,1,1)}\oplus V^*{}^{(1,1,1)}$. Your questions could also be phrased as saying whether this subspace of $V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V^*$ can be defined using a "single" set of combinatorial equations. This seems unlikely to me.

Comment: I see. It _looks_ like a formula that will be "true because of" a simple combinatorial Eureka moment, but maybe it just doesn't have one. Thanks for weighing in.

Comment: I would agree that the fact that the space of curvature tensors is this particular subspace of 4-tensors is rather mysterious. I was there when this was all worked out by the authors, and at the time we all found it to be a really cool fact.